# High luminosity tolerant USB camera

Tags: usb, video-camera, camera

I'm looking for a high luminosity tolerant USB camera.

I'm working on a project in which I have to install a small USB camera in a surgical illumination device. The objective is to stream videos of surgeries to students in medical schools.

I'm currently working with an ELP-USBFHD06H-FV Sony Lens (http://www.webcamerausb.com/elpusbfhd06hfv-sony-lens-usb-with-webcam-p-198.html) camera. This camera works well under low luminosity, however when the illumination system is turned on some filtering must be applied to the video, such as exposure and brightness manipulation. This is where the problem arises: when the filtering is applied in the high luminosity scenario the image quality gets severely degraded (being the main issue the appearance of interference beats).

This quality degradation is the reason why I'm looking for a high luminosity tolerant USB camera. The luminosity measure under which I'm working is 140000 lux.

Can anyone recommend an USB camera the would work well under the given conditions?

Recommendations to other, more specialized, forums would also be appreciated.

Thank you!